# C# Invoke Action Cross Thread Access

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, action, invoke

greetings, im new to programming.

at the moment my application uses delegates to process/execute methods that reside in a another class/object.

but i was getting an error stating that they were residing in separte threads. so after searching the web i came up with this:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { this.ChatRichTextBox.AppendText(EventArgs.commMessage); }));
```

this has worked fine accept i have no idea whats going on. i just pasted the code and it worked.

at present now though i have a need for doing this differently as the compiler says it cant do > < != operations within this action.

please advise on how best to implement this?

thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "it cant do > < != operations".  can you post that code?

Comment: i would but im away from my computer right now. until then. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Access to Windows Forms controls is
>   not inherently thread safe. If you
>   have two or more threads manipulating
>   the state of a control, it is possible
>   to force the control into an
>   inconsistent state. Other
>   thread-related bugs are possible, such
>   as race conditions and deadlocks. It
>   is important to make sure that access
>   to your controls is performed in a
>   thread-safe way.
>
> It is unsafe to call a control from a
>   thread other than the one that created
>   the control without using the Invoke
>   method.

- MSDN:  "[How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)"

Comment: Is this related to > < != operations?

Comment: It explains cross-thread operations (which the OP doesn't have an understanding of)